# Probability that an event will happen given continuous probability distribution

Tags: probability

This question actually came from watching a weather report, so here's the weather related analogy:

Let's say that the probability of rain today is  $f(t)$, where max of f is 0.4 and min is 0, with time t in hours.  If $t \in [0, 24]$ Can I claim that the probability of rain in the next 24 hours is just max of f?

I feel that it isn't, since $f$ is a continuous distribution while the question in asking is discrete, but I don't know how to mix the to.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  The "probability of rain today" would appear to be a number, not a function of time.  Maybe $f(t)$ is the probability of rain at the moment $t$?  But it isn't clear to me how that function works (I mean, rain at time $t=1$ has to be equivalent to rain at time $t=1.0001$)...can you clarify?

Comment: Do you have additional information about f(t) than just the max and the min value ?

Comment: Not sure I made my objection clear:  Let's say you only sample hourly, so you have the probability of rain at each hour.  Now these are hardly independent events!  But you don't tell us how they relate to each other.  Absent that knowledge I don't see how we can integrate it up to get the "probability of rain today".

Comment: I see. I meant, that $f(t)$ is the probability of rain at a given instant $t$. That is, it's the continuous probability distribution of rain throughout the day. For the sake of concreteness, let's assume it's a Gaussian distribution. I'm not extremely concerned about where the mean is/ the standard deviation since I'm more interested in the general idea. However, if the answer depends on the type of distribution that's good to know too.

Comment: But surely you don't want "rain at nearby time intervals" to be independent events.    It can't switch from rain to not-rain a million times in a second.

Comment: A standard setting is when $f$ denotes the PDF of the random time $T$ when it rains for the first time, then the probability that it rains before time $24$ is $$P(T<24)=\int_0^{24}f(t)dt$$ Of course, some portions of the statement of the question do not fit, for example "the probability of rain today is $f(t)$", but since it is difficult to attribute a meaning to this assertion anyway, my bet would go to this interpretation.

Comment: @Did: I agree with your interpretation, that's what I was trying to get across.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The discrete analogy would be the following. Suppose that $f$ is discrete with probability of rain at hour $i$ equal $i/100$. Then, we have $0\%$ probability that it rains at midnight and $23\%$ that it rains at $11$ pm, but you cannot claim the probability of rain today is $23\%$. The real way to do this is to condition at the specific time of day, so you get
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}[\text{rain today}]
 &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{no rain today}]\\
 &= 1 - \prod_{h = 0}^{23}
             \left(1- \mathbb{P}[\text{rain now}|\text{now is } t]\right) \\
 &= 1 - \prod_{h = 0}^{23} \left(1 - \frac{h}{100}\right) \\
 &= 1 - \frac{1}{100^{24}} \prod_{h = 0}^{23} (100-h) \\
 &= 1 - \frac{100!}{76! \cdot 100^{24}} \\
 &\approx 1 - 0.049 \\
 &= 95.1\%
\end{split}
$$

Comment: May I note that $f$ is not a probability function, since $$\sum_{i=1}^{23}f(i)=\sum_{i=0}^23>1$$ However, I agree with your point that we cannot claim that the maximum of $f$ is the probability of rain today, but, wouldn't it be more logical that the probability of rain today would be the mean value of $f$?

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος "May I note that $f$ is not a probability function" Do we know that?

Comment: I'm talking about the $f$ provided in the answer. A discrete probability function over a space $\Omega$ has to satisfy:
$$\sum_{x\in\Omega}f(x)=1$$

Comment: @ΒασίληςΜάρκος Did is correct, just divide the entire $f$ by $\sum_h f(h)$ to get a probability function, it does not change anything materially.